# PhantomJS page.render blank white background image on 403

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, phantom-dsl, mocha-phantomjs

While performing screenshots of pages using PhantomJS, I noticed that it won't capture the screenshot if response status is `403` or `Forbidden`.

- Test1:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

`phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --ssl-ciphers=ALL --debug=yes
test.js`

- Test2:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://cheggnet.com', function() {
  page.render('test.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

```
2020-01-28T22:50:02 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error: QNetworkReply::NetworkError(ContentOperationNotPermittedError) ( "Error downloading http://cheggnet.com/ - server replied: Forbidden" ) URL: "http://cheggnet.com/"
```

- which outputs the blank white background image, here I would like to take the screenshot of actual `forbidden or 403` page itself instead it outputs blank white background.